# What type of lever of a hydraulic rim brake is this?

Tags: brakes, rim-brake, brake-levers

What is the manufacturer and the model of this brake lever of a hydraulic rim brake?

[image: Photo of the break lever, which has a number 11 on it]

I am puzzled because it's connected to a Magura hydraulic rim brake caliper, and there is a 11 on it - so I always assumed that it is a Magura HS11. By web  search, I could verify that it is actually not the HS 11 - but I couldn't find the real one. (Specification `11' directs reliably to the HS 11...) Does anyone know this type?

Comment: I'm confused.  That doesn't look like a hydraulic lever (no reservoir, or at least not much of one).  Can you post a picture of the caliper as well please?

Comment: @DeletedUser: Oh it is, your answer was correct. It is apparently the (old?) HS 11 model. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the picture [here](http://www.bikerecyclery.com/magura-hs11-hydraulic-rim-brake-exc-but-for-parts-only-cracked-lever/) I would assume it is a Magura HS 11, but perhaps a older model.  The link has a different color body, but the style is the same.  Additional searching yields other similar results, some with the [same colors](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NOS-Magura-HS-11-Hydraulic-Rim-Brake-Rear-HS11-Trial-brake-Trekking-/153318882426?nma=true&si=mkpwASlW3gF6wvBnOUk6kmNHj%252Fk%253D&orig_cvip=true&nordt=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557) even.